# Errors on Web-links: list of links in Category on update to php vn 7.4

Tags: weblinks

This is the error message we get on a page generated form a menu item using Web Links > List Web Links in a Category:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/milfordu3a/public_html/components/com_weblinks/views/category/tmpl/default_items.php on line 17
```

This is for php vn. 7.4.9 and Joomla vn. 3.9.20

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Weblinks has been decoupled from Joomla and it now maintained separately. Try installing the latest version: https://github.com/joomla-extensions/weblinks/releases

Comment: Also, set error reporting to none on the production site.

Comment: The version of com_weblinks is probably more important than php or Joomla versions here. In any case, the view you reference has not been updated in at least 3+ years - https://github.com/joomla-extensions/weblinks/blame/master/src/components/com_weblinks/views/category/tmpl/default_items.php - so I suspect you are using an archaic version of the component. Update the component and see how that goes.